# What's the name of this PCIE power connector?

Tags: connector, identification

I have a standard computer power supply unit pci-e power 8 pin connector like this one:

[image: pcie connector]
<sub>(source: [playtool.com](http://www.playtool.com/pages/psuconnectors/pcie8.jpg))</sub>

I want to power my own PCB via a connector like this and I am having trouble find the name of the pcb socket housing for it. I have gotten to the point where I think that it is a molex mini-fit, dual row, but I can't find anything that would have a matching square/round pin configuration.

What is the name of the socket for this connector and where can I buy one?

UPDATE

The similar but incompatible connector I was finding is called EPS. Here is a nice page showing various PC connector types and their names
http://www.playtool.com/pages/psuconnectors/connectors.html

Molex 45558-0003 is the equivalent 6 pin version. Need to find the 8 pin sku.

Other names I have found: 8-pin PCI Express auxiliary power. The only place I found where you can buy one is http://www.moddiy.com/products/8%252dPin-Graphics-Card-PCIe-Male-Header-Connector-%252d-90%25-Angled-%252d-Black.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Molex Mini-Fit family is probably similar to what you're looking for: http://www.molex.com/molex/products/group?channel=products&key=minifit_products

Many distributors are selling these. In Europe, you can try TME: http://www.tme.pl/

Comment: Yes, I narrowed it down to Mini-Fit Jr: http://www.molex.com/molex/products/family?channel=products&chanName=family&key=graphics_power

Comment: Unfortunately it's not a normal Mini-Fit JR. As you have noticed it has special keying. While i've seen unbranded versions of this connector for sale at various PC modding places i've never seen a SKU from a major connector vendor for it.