# What are the part numbers for PCI-E 8-pin and 6-pin power connectors?

Tags: power, connector, pcie

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/af/PCI_Express_Power_Supply_Connector-female_PNr%C2%B00438.jpg

I believe they are Molex Mini-Fit series but I can't find the exact match. Thanks.

Found an [old thread](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/87053/whats-the-name-of-this-pcie-power-connector?rq=1). It points to some no-name connector, which is nice but I need a part I can specify in a design...

Comment: Contact Molex directly and ask

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The 6-pin versions are:

- 45558-0003 - (*) Molex Mini-Fit JR, PCIe Applications, Right-Angle, 6-pin Header
- 45718-0002 - Molex Mini-Fit JR, PCIe Applications, Vertical, 6-pin Header
- 45559-0002 - Molex Mini-Fit JR, PCIe Applications, 6-pin Receptacle

The 8-pin versions are:

- 45586-0005 - Molex Mini-Fit JR, PCIe Applications, Right-Angle, 8-pin Header  with polarisation link.
- Vertical header part numbers unknown.
- 45587-0004 - Molex Mini-Fit JR, PCIe Applications, 8-pin Receptacle with polarisation link.

---

(*) The original part number was 45558-0002 part has been superseded by 45558-0003.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the official Mini Fit (Jr) for PCI Express specification by Molex.

https://www.molex.com/pdm_docs/ps/PS-45558-001-001.pdf

All part numbers officially compatible are listed in section 2.1.

Comment: Unfortunately like Tom's answer that only covers the 6-pin connectors.